# How do you allow ICMP Echo Requests on a Cisco ASA 55xx Router?

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, icmp

I'm very new to managing Cisco equipment, so bear with me.

I'm configuring a Cisco ASA 5505 router for my office, and I am reasonably competent enough with the console to configure the basics -- our business needs are not extravagant. Our pings are being dropped by the router, however.

How do I configure the router to allow ICMP Echo Requests? Are there other types of ICMP requests that should be allowed? What are the potential downsides of allowing them all?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that you haven't change the `global_policy policy-map`, have an access-group from_outside on interface outside and that you want to allow icmp echo on the outside interface, here is what to type:

```
policy-map global_policy
 class inspection_default
  inspect icmp
  exit
 exit
access-list from_outside extended permit icmp any any echo
```

I would only allow echo request on outside interface.
You may also probably want to take a look to the [ASDM](http://www.cisco.com/web/go/asdm)

Comment: Thanks, I've been using the ASDM as well but 99% of all google results refer to the console commands, so it seems wise to get comfortable with it.

Comment: However, any new classes that you may happen to take for Cisco, are de-emphasizing the CLI.  That being said, there are some things that you will want to ONLY do through ASDM.